# TokenMismatchException in Laravel App in Godaddy Server

Tags: laravel, server, shared-hosting, csrf-protection

I hosted my laravel (version 5.5) application in Godaddy server ,but Im getting error :

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)

when submitting ContactUs Form . Any one please help me .

in my `config/session.php` i set

> 'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

and also given `storage folder permission 777`

but it is not working . anyone please help me to solve out.

Comment: did u find solution?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski , not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you use **`csrf_token()`** in your forms,and we do not have to solve that.

So make:

chmod 777 storage/framework/sessions/

Clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`

Generate new app key: `php artisan key:generate`

Good luck!